# Perl regular expression to match an IP address

Tags: regex, perl, ip

I have written this code, but it does not work.
Can someone point out the issue?

```
sub match_ip()
{
  my $ip = "The IP address is 216.108.225.236:60099";
  if($ip =~ /(\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\:\d{1-5})/)
  {
      print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I wanted to just extract the IP address, not do any validation.

Comment: Instead of writing your own regex you might want to consider using a well documented and tested module f.ex. [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Regexp%3A%3ACommon&mode=all)

Comment: There's more than a couple issues here. Use one of the modules, or look at all the things the modules do to do it right. :)

Comment: Are you trying to validate or just extract the IP address? Cause it does an awful job of the former.

Comment: I want to just extract, not validate

Comment: Well, you also don't want to extract things that can't be IP addresses, so validating, which is extremely easy to do, helps reduce the false positives.

Comment: The thing is, just for validation, I don't want to make my script dependent on any module. I am expecting only valid IP address in the file which I am processing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `{1-3}` to `{1,3}` same for `{1-5}` -> `{1,5}`

Comment: @briandfoy - Is this an acceptable answer for you as well? As I mentioned before, sometimes OP wants simple solution that solve his problem, not complex code. In this case, no IP verification is needed, as probably OP needs to parse output that contains valid IP addresses. So this answer is exactly what OP was looking for. Thanks M42 to post simple answer that meet OP's needs.

Comment: @stackoverflow: Thank you. The first 3 answers are correct according to OP. That's why I've upvoted the 2 other than mine.

Comment: @M42 - My post (answer) on the bottom was downvoted for no reason by #briandfoy and his followers, so I tried to comment your answer for him to show that those answers are good. Yours answer was very first one, so you deserve upvotes and acceptance.

Comment: This answers the regex issue, but not the task issue. I don't think this meets the needs, just the wants. Those two are often at odds.

Comment: @briandfoy:You're right but that's what the OP wants, resolves the regex issue.

Comment: @M42 - Correct, M42. It was resolved by regex, as OP asked for. Unfortunately #briandfoy very often try to change simple tasks to complex issues, which in most of time is not what OPs want.

Answer (score 7):

In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI here is another: the [`Regexp::Common::net`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anet) portion of [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) may have regexen that you desire.

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the most on point since it provides a usable solution applicable to both IPv4 and IPv6. Although OP seemed to focus only on IPv4. Surely others who will come here will be interested in IPv6 regular expression as well.

Comment: Could you perhaps update your answer to include a bit more explanation as to how to use this within a script? Right now it's just a link.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use [`Data::Validate::IP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aValidate%3a%3aIP), with the caveat that it won't recognize the port, so you'll have to `split` on `:`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Validate::IP;

my $ip_with_port="216.108.225.236:60099";
my $ip=(split /:/,$ip_with_port)[0];

my $validator=Data::Validate::IP->new;

if($validator->is_ipv4($ip))
{
  print "Yep, $ip is a valid IPv4 address.\n";
}
else
{
  print "Nope, $ip is not a valid IPv4 address.\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
Yep, 216.108.225.236 is a valid IPv4 address.
```

Comment: The OP's question is to find a match (regex), not validate IP address. Your script use IP address as input, but OP's input is a string that may contain IP address, but not just IP address.

Comment: @stackoverflow - TIMTOWTDI.  In addition, a) the OP was trying to put together a regex *in order to* validate an IP address and b) if you look at the source code of Data::Validate::IP, it uses regexes.  So my answer *is* relevant whether you like it or not.

Comment: Why so strong words? I do like your answer, but I commented your answer for one and only reason - I don't see in OP's question any note that he is looking for IP validation... and I don't see it there even now, when your comments saying that OP is asking for that. Anyway... Your code is  right solution for IP validation. Period. Just not sure if that is what OP wants. Maybe he will come back to us and will clarify his needs...

Answer (score 2):

Replace the dashes with commas.

```
/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5})/
```

Answer (score 2):

Though there are well documented and tested modules at CPAN to match and validate IP addresses but there must be some solid reason for you not to use it.  Personally I never had a real reason to use them for validation purpose either since I trusted/feeded the input.

Here is a shorter version of your regex, with it's own pitfalls:

```
while (my $ip = <DATA>)  {
    chomp $ip;
    # older version
    # if($ip =~ /(\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\.\d{1-3}\:\d{1-5})/)

    # see below for explanation
    if ($ip =~ /\b(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d{1,5})\b/)
    {
        print "$ip - matches\n";
    } else {
        print "$ip - does not match\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
216.108.225.236:60099
4.2.2.1:1
216.108.225.236:0
1216.1108.1225.1236:1234
216.108.225.236x:123
9216.108.225.236:8472
10.10.10.10
```

Results:

```
216.108.225.236:60099 - matches
4.2.2.1:1 - matches
216.108.225.236:0 - matches
1216.1108.1225.1236:1234 - does not match
216.108.225.236x:123 - does not match
9216.108.225.236:8472 - does not match
10.10.10.10 - does not match
```

Explanation:

```
/\b             # word boundary
(               # start memory capture group 1
\d{1,3}         # one to three digits, first octat
(:?             # start non memory capture group, notice ?:
  \.\d{1,3}     # a literal dot followed by an ip octet
)               # end non memory capture group
{3}             # three times of dots and ip octets
:               # match a colon
\d{1,5}         # port number, one to five digits
)               # end of memory capture group 1
\b              # word boundary
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are going to do this much work, you might as well make the regex match the right range of digits. You should test for things such as 127.1 too, a valid address that used to bite me when I'd do this sort of thing wrong.

Comment: Your test data is incomplete. Something like `333.108.225.236:123` is an invalid IP but would pass your check.

Comment: @Will, Brian : you must have missed " since I trusted/feeded the input " in Ashish description. Also sometime using the external modules is not possible, not welcomed, not desired,  in which case "manual" solution is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
my $ip = "195.249.61.14";

my @ips = (
    "set protocols bgp group IBGP-RRCL-CUSTOMER neighbor 195.249.61.142",
    "set protocols bgp group IBGP-RRCL-CUSTOMER neighbor 195.249.61.14",
    "set protocols bgp group IBGP-RRCL-CUSTOMER neighbor 195.249.61.141"
);

foreach (@ips) {
   print "$_\n" if ( /\b$ip\b/ );
}
```

Output:

```
set protocols bgp group IBGP-RRCL-CUSTOMER neighbor 195.249.61.14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$str = 'IP address is : 70.21.311.105';

    if ($str =~ m/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/) {
        if ($1 <= 255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <= 255 && $4 <= 255 ) {
            print "Valid $str\n";
    } else {
          print "invalid IP $str\n";
    }
}


__END__
```

Comment: No need of second `if condition`, that can be written with first one like this `if($str =~ m/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/ && ($1<=255  && $2<=255 && $3<=255  && $4<=255 ))`

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of  :

```
/((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5})/
```

This expression is the same as the OPs except with 2 changes,

1. The dash "-" becomes a comma, i.e. `{1,3}` and `{1,5}` , as other answers have indicated already,
2. and my change is just shortening the expression by combining `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.` into one .i.e. `(\d{1,3}\.)` with the `{3}` to match exactly 3 times

thanks @starball for the guidance ;)

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$variablename=~m/((((0-9)|((1-9)(0-9))|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[5][0-5]))\.){3})((0-9)|((1-9)(0-9))|(1([0-9]){2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FH,"<fileName.txt") or die "file not found ,$_";
while(my $line=<FH>)
{
push(my @arr,($line));
foreach my $arrVal (@arr)
{           
if($arrVal=~/IPv4 Address(?=.*\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2  [0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3})\b)/)
{
print "$arrVal\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the following regex to make sure that the quad's aren't bigger then 255, it also "reuses" the digit matching instead of copypasting it 4 times.

```
my $rx = qr/^(?!(\.))(\.?(\d{1,3})(?(?{$^N > 255})(*FAIL))){4}$/;
if('192.168.1.2' =~ $rx){
  print "OK\n";
}
```

It uses a few features from perl regex matching (man perlre):

- (*FAIL): stops pattern matching and fails
- (?(condition)...): conditional match
- (?{ code }): used within that condition

Comment: This fails for $rx =  "27.34"

Answer (score -2):

```
$ip = "10.255.256.1";

# will accept valid ips
if ($ip =~ m/^([1|2][0-9]{1,2})\.([0-255]{1,3}\.){2}[0-255]{1,3}/ && ($1 <=255)) {

  print "This is a valid ip: $ip \n";
 } else {
   print "This is not a valid ip: $ip \n";
}
```

Comment: -1 You are reinventing water, poorly. This disallows any address whose first octet is >= 200, for starters.

Comment: I think you should learn about Ip address.Class C address will not  be >=200.usually we will check for class c address only.let me know when you would check for other class address

Comment: What does class C networks have with anything to do?  In the modern world, networks are classless anyway.  And the OP's example address is 216.x.x.x.  And `[0-255]` in a regex does not do at all what you think it should do.