# bash + how to capture IP address from line

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have many configuration files , 
the line that start with LINE word have IP  address

My target to read the line that start with LINE word from the file and print only the IP address

The problem is that IP address can be in any field in the line so I can’t capture the IP according to field number

example

```
grep LINE file1.txt

LINE /home/Ariate/run.pl "Voda STS 4 Test -  " "102841" && ssh 17.77.170.130 -p 2022 



grep LINE file2.txt

LINE /home/Ariate/run.pl 137.77.170.30 "Voda STS 4 Test -  " "102841" && ssh  ACTIVE
```

please advice how to capture the IP address from the line ( solution can be also with perl one liner )

expected results

```
echo $IP_FROM_LINE

17.77.170.130



echo $IP_FROM_LINE

137.77.170.30
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10161963/725418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this `grep -oE`:

```
grep -oE '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file
17.77.170.130
137.77.170.30
```

OR else:

```
grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file
```

Comment: Output shown is copy/paste by running it on your data.

Comment: [See this working example](http://ideone.com/UUqP8s) You can also try: `grep -oP`

Comment: this will match any grouping of 4 blocks of digits separated by '.', many of which will be outside the valid ip address range of 0-255.

Comment: @maihabunash: Glad to know it worked out. Of course I kept it simple to avoid a complex looking regex to validate all edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lne 'print $1 if /^LINE.*\b($RE{net}{IPv4})/'
```

Comment: @ikegami greedy match will capture last ip if there are more than one on the same line (and with possible backtracking?).

Comment: Is that a question? `.*?` will backtrack by adding characters to find the first. `.*` will backtrack by removing characters to find last.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{2,3}(\.[0-9]{2,3}){3}'
```

matches

```
17.77.170.130
137.77.170.30
```

or

```
grep -oP '\d{2}(\.\d{2}){3}'
```

if your `grep` supports `-P` option.

both of them works with the data you have given.

But if you want really worried of what to be matched, use

```
grep -Eo '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
```

which would match excat ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you the desired IP addresses:

```
grep -oP '^LINE.*\b\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file
```

To place the result in a variable as request, you'll need to iterate of the results as follows:

```
grep -oP '^LINE.*\b\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file |
while read IP_FROM_LINE ; do
    echo $IP_FROM_LINE
done
```