# perl regex match all IPv4 address

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to scrap apache status page for IP address listed,  an example [apache status page](https://www.apache.org/server-status).

```
<tr><td><b>0-35</b></td><td>1791</td><td>1/1079/387615</td><td>G
</td><td>5541.08</td><td>379</td><td>557</td><td>135.0</td><td>33.04</td><td>20992.04
</td><td>83.60.245.1</td><td nowrap></td><td nowrap></td></tr>
```

I have downloaded the page

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use LWP::Simple;
    use feature 'say';
    use File::Slurp;
    my $content = get('http://www.apache.org/server-status') or die 'Unable to get page';

    write_file('filename',$content);
```

How can I create an array of of IP address found?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl regular expression to match an IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161963/perl-regular-expression-to-match-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find all entries of groups of 1-3 digits separated by dot and verify that each of then is in 0-255 range.

```
while ($content =~ /(?<!\d)(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})(?!\d)/g) {
    if (
        $1 >= 0 && $1 <= 255 &&
        $2 >= 0 && $2 <= 255 &&
        $3 >= 0 && $3 <= 255 &&
        $4 >= 0 && $4 <= 255
    ) {
        print "$1.$2.$3.$4\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Made it so 1000.0.0.0 isn't considered an IP address.

Comment: There's no need for the `>= 0` tests, as you're matching only digits, so there can't be any negative numbers (the dash/negative sign isn't matched by `\d`)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the `RegExp::Common` ([Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2016020301/lib/Regexp/Common/net.pm)) module available on the CPAN, like so:

```perl
use Regexp::Common qw /net/;

while ($content =~ m!<td>($RE{net}{IPv4})</td>!g) {
  print "IP: $1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}
```

This is not enough to exclusively match all ipv4 address, but should be enough for your page.

For example, it would also match `522.53.0.0`.

Demo: http://regexr.com/3dc1q