# Perl: Verifying user input

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a program where I need to verify if the user input is the first 2 segments of an IP, I already have the part to verify if the pattern is 000.000 but I'm having problems with verifying if the digits are under 256. Even the when I try to print the @abc array it is blank.

```
@abc = split(".", $ARGV[0]);

foreach $a (@abc){
    if $a != [0 .. 256] {
        print "not an ip class"
    }
    else {
        print "it's an ip class"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl regular expression to match an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161963/perl-regular-expression-to-match-an-ip-address)

Comment: OP can use a regex to solve the problem, but that wouldn't explain much about what's going wrong in this snippet, which is the real question, I would imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always start your Perl programs with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The first argument to [`split`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split) is a regex. You can give it a string, but that will just interpret the contents of the string as a regex at runtime.

`.` is special in a regex, matching any character. You have to escape it:

```
my @parts = split /\./, $ARGV[0];
```

Don't use variables called `$a` or `$b`; those are a bit special and used internally by [`sort`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/sort).

`!=` compares two numbers. You can't use it to see if an element is part of a list.

You need to do something like

```
for my $n (@parts) {
    if ($n <= 255) {
        print "ok\n";
    } else {
        print "not ok\n";
    }
}
```

If you have already validated that `$n` consists of digits only, it cannot be negative.